# Drop down menu doesn't go to the link when clicked

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am just learning how to use javascript and I was trying to create a drop down menu. Unfortunately, when I click on the drop down menu, nothing happen and it doesn't go to the link.

Here is my html:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <div class="wrapper-catego">
            <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
              <span>Categories</span>
                 <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href=" url here ">Category 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href=" url here ">Category 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href=" url here ">Category 3</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         ​</div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript is this:

```
              <script type="text/javascript">

        function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
            this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

          $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `return false;` in the end of that function:

```
            obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });
```

`return false;` is equivalent to event.preventDefault(), which cancel the normal behavior of the event (here, the link opening).

**EDIT**:

Ok, so removing the **return false;** is the good solution, but the dropdown doesn't show because of the onclick event on document. The class active is automatically removed by this function. You have to detect where the mouse is clicked to remove or not the active class. 
I suggest to use the mouseup event instead of click event.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bBQZy/10/)

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var dropdown = $(".wrapper-dropdown-3");
        if (!dropdown.is(e.target) && dropdown.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            dropdown.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Getz, thanks for your reply. However, when I removed the return false; it stopped the drop down menu from appearing. the drop menu wouldn't show at all.

Comment: Hi Kiyan! You should provide a  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduce your issue, I can't help more without that.

Comment: Hi Getz, here the is fiddle: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/Femerall/bBQZy/) Thanks in advance mate!

Comment: @Kiyan : I've updated my answer, it should work now ;)